# Undesired merged columns after opening .dat file with pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, nan

I am opening a two-column .dat file using the following:

```
# reading the data
df_topex = pd.read_csv('datasets/TOPEX.dat', 
                       sep='\t', #tab as separator
                       index_col=0, #convert first column to index
                       names=["Time", "Anomaly"] #naming the headers
                      )
df_topex
```

The output is a data frame with the first column with both the information of Time and Anomaly and the second table as NaNs as shown in the image below:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can it be avoided?

**P.S.:** The original file has no headers.

Comment: is your data tab separated? you can try replace `'\t'` with `'\s'`.

Comment: Oh... I feel silly now... I tried '\s+' and it did work. Is there a way in which I can check what the actual separator is to avoid this confusion in the future?